# TMREWSync (TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer) questions

Tags: multithreading, delphi, locking

I have questions about TMREWSync:

1. Is it possible to upgrade Read lock to Write lock without unlocking?
2. Don't understand what I should do if BeginWrite returns false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, TMREWSync supports lock upgrades. Use it like: `BeginRead` ... `BeginWrite` ... `EndWrite` ... `EndRead`.
2. Source code in `System.SysUtils` states:

> The function result of BeginWrite indicates whether another thread got the write lock while the current thread was waiting for the write lock. Return value of True means that the write lock was acquired without any intervening modifications by other threads.  Return value of False means another thread got the write lock while you were waiting, so the resource protected by the MREWS object should be considered modified. Any samples of the protected resource should be discarded.

My suggestion is that you write your algorithm so that it doesn't depend on this return value. The source code agrees with me:

> In general, it's better to just always reacquire samples of the protected resource after obtaining a write lock.  The boolean result of BeginWrite and the RevisionLevel property help cases where reacquiring the samples is computationally expensive or time consuming.